# Why are memory addresses are represented using hexadecimal numbers?

Tags: language-agnostic, memory, hex

Whenever I see C programs that refer directly to a specific location on the memory (e.g. a memory barrier) it is done with hexadecimal numbers, also in windows when you get a segfualt it presents the memory being segfualted with a hexadecimal number.
For example: `*(0x12DF)`
I am wondering why memory addresses are represented using hexadecimal numbers?
Is there a special reason for that or is it just a convention?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Memory is often manipulated in terms of larger units, such as pages or segments, which
tend to have sizes that are powers of 2.  So if addresses are expressed in hex, it's
much easier to read them as page+offset or similar constructs.  Decimal is difficult because
of that pesky factor of 5, and binary addresses are too long to be easily readable.

Comment: It's worth noting that even in systems without any concept of virtual memory, hardware itself has for a very long time almost always divided memory into regions whose sizes and boundaries are either powers of two or small multiples thereof (e.g. a standard VIC-20 had 8-bit RAM from 0x0000-0x03FF and 0x1000-0x1FFF, and 4-bit RAM from 0x9400-0x97FF).

Comment: Why do you mean "Decimal is difficult because of that pesky factor of 5" ? conversion between base 10 and base 2 ?

Answer (score 12):

Its a much shorter way to represent what would otherwise be written in binary. It is also very nice and easy to convert hex to binary and back. Each 4 digits of binary corresponds to one digit of hex.

Answer (score 7):

Convention and convenience:  hex shows more clearly what relationship various pointers have to address segmenting.  (For example, shared libraries are usually loaded on even hex boundaries, and the data segment likewise is on an even boundary.)  DEC minicomputer convention actually preferred octal, but IBM's hex preference won out in practice.

(As for why this matters:  what's easier to remember, `0xb73eb000` or 3074338816?  It's the address of one of the shared objects in my current shell on `jinx`.)

Answer (score 1):

It's the shortest, common number format, thus the numbers don't take up much place and everybody knows what they mean.

Comment: Even Base32 is shorter, but the advantage of hex is that one digit is exactly half of an octet.

Answer (score -2):

Computer only understands binary language which is collection of 0's and 1's. That means ON/OFF. As in case of the human readability the binary number which may be representing some address or data has to be converted into human readable format. Hexadecimal is one of them. But the question can be why we have converted binary to HEX only why not decimal, octal etc. Answer is HEX is the one which can be easily converted with the least amount of overhead on both HW as well as SW. thats why we are using addresses as HEX. But internally they are used as binary only.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: The ease of conversion in hardware or software has nothing to do with it; it's trivial regardless of base. The use of hexadecimal (or octal) is for the ease of conversion by humans and pattern recognition by humans.