# C# pointers what does X in the Console.WriteLine signify?

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, console-application, unmanaged

I was just going through the C# pointers description on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/pointer-related-operators#pointer-member-access-operator and came across this example :

```
unsafe
{
    char letter = 'A';
    char* pointerToLetter = &letter;
    Console.WriteLine($"Value of the `letter` variable: {letter}");

    // Look at the end of the following statement
    Console.WriteLine($"Address of the `letter` variable: {(long)pointerToLetter:X}");

    *pointerToLetter = 'Z';
    Console.WriteLine($"Value of the `letter` variable after update: {letter}");
}
// Output is similar to:
// Value of the `letter` variable: A
// Address of the `letter` variable: DCB977DDF4
// Value of the `letter` variable after update: Z
```

What does `X` in the following statement do ?

```
Console.WriteLine($"Address of the `letter` variable: {(long)pointerToLetter:X}");
```

Why not just

```
Console.WriteLine($"Address of the `letter` variable: {(long)pointerToLetter}");
```

Comment: Uppercase hex format specifier: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings  Addresses are more useful when displayed in hex. For example, you can see memory alignment at a glance based on lower bits.

Answer (score 3):

Formats the long as hexadecimal. You could add a number after it too to specify the width (padded with leading zeroes)

```
Console.WriteLine($"Address of the `letter` variable: {(long)pointerToLetter:X8}");

--> Address of the `letter` variable: 00001EA4
```

---

```
Console.WriteLine($"Address of the `letter` variable: {(long)pointerToLetter:X}");
```

Is equivalent to

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Address of the `letter` variable: {0:X}", (long)pointerToLetter));
```

Is equivalent to

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Address of the `letter` variable: {0}", ((long)pointerToLetter).ToString("X")));
```

---

Why not just

```
Console.WriteLine($"Address of the `letter` variable: {(long)pointerToLetter}");
```

You ask.. well, because it'll print the memory address out in base 10 rather than hex. For a longer discussion on why we represent memory addresses in hex see [Why are memory addresses are represented using hexadecimal numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329916/why-are-memory-addresses-are-represented-using-hexadecimal-numbers)